# how to reduce signal noises

Tags: signal-analysis, noise, oscillator

I am trying generate guided waves on simple metallic plate through piezo-ceramic material, I place two piezo on the surface of the plate at the different location and through Arbitrary pulse generator, I generate the Gaussian pulse of 150KHz and excite the one piezo. This excitation generate guided waves which is sensed by the other piezo. but the problem is, the output signal has very high noises and very low SNR ratio, I hardly even see the signal on the oscilloscope, but whenever I switch to the normal sine wave of the same frequency, and shut off the arbitrary and burst option, then the output signal will have very high resolution and SNR value.

actually I have mechanical background, so I coundnt figure out the source of these noises. As u can see the blue signals, the output one has very low amplitude, where each box has value of 50mV, Moreover, when I remove the probes, these noises still persist there. Can u please guide me what data I should provide to avoid these noises. 
Please someone guide me how to reduce signal noises,[image]

Comment: Can you share a CSV of the values of the signal?

Comment: Thanks for your replay, here is the file  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L3kjo08l9_zYnhlU1j6hTAwP9Nyi0FGM/view?usp=sharing